# Running a javascript function from a string / data parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to run a javascript function which is stored in a data attribute.

e.g.

```
<form data-success="test">...</form>

$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var successFunction = $(this).data('success');

    // Run success function here
});

function test(){
    alert('run');
};
```

Is this possible or is there a better solution?

Comment: Please be a little bit clearer. I don't see any reason for this to happen given your example.

Comment: eval("string function") is your friend but not recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you storing application logic in your DOM in the first place? Why not store the function in your backing business logic in JavaScript?

This *will* prove to be a maintainability issue. Do *not* do this, instead store your functions in code and separate the logic of your presentation from what happens when it runs.

The *simplest* way is to classify your form and run a function accordingly, a better approach could be using something like an MV* pattern but let's not diverge. Here is the simplest solution I could think of without storing data attributes. This still does not do proper separation of concerns but it is a lot simpler than a data attibute.

...

JavaScript with jQuery:

```
/now we select by class, and not just any form
$('.successForm').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    test();
});

function test(){
    alert('run');
};
```

<sup>THAT said, it *can* be done. `eval($(this).data("success"))` - please *don't* do this though, this bit is just here for completeness</sup>

Comment: You don't necessarily need eval: `window[$(this).data("success")]()`

Comment: I am creating a private system and it has a load of forms that do pretty much the same thing except the success function differs per form.

Comment: @Juhana That's clever, but pretty much the same in my opinion, you're still taking a string of code and evaluating it.

Comment: @MattPawley If it's a whole system _please_ do not use data attributes. Have JavaScript objects backing the system. Selecting based on classes is a primitive approach to differentiate the function based on the form class. I _hate_ to suggest a library, but have you considered something like KnockoutJS or AngularJS to handle the basic parts of separation of concerns for you? If this is something that has to repeat a lot of times in your code, the command pattern in Knockout might really help you.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum uh, no, it has nothing to do with eval, any more than accessing any other object (or array!) property with the bracket notation.

Comment: Sorry guys, neither eval($(this).data("success")) or window[$(this).data("success")]() seem to fire the function - any ideas?

Comment: @Juhana This is gray territory since it's _not_ like accessing any other object. What's actually being done here is accessing a host object, the behavior of this is not defined in JavaScript - it's defined in the DOM API. When you do someJSObject["someFunction"]() that's _completely_ different even if it's syntactically similar :)

Comment: @MattPawley Please do __not__ use eval for this. I just put it there to mention it's _possible_. Do __NOT__ use eval for this. It will get you nothing but __PAIN__. It's there for the sake of completeness, not to be used in production code. Do proper separation of concerns instead. Adding arbitrary functions as data attributes in the DOM scares me :S

Comment: Sorry my bad - the function was not within the window object. I appreciate the concerns and understand the reasoning; however for the project it does actually make sense to pass the functions in via data attributes. I will in future not use this as a general coding convention - thanks!

Comment: This is why we can't have nice things :(